# CMake Error (configure_file): configure_file error configuring file

Tags: cmake, doxygen

I am working on a project on **c++** and need to execute a **CMakeLists.txt** file to run it. I installed *cmake*, *doxygen*, *cmake-curses-gui* and *make* using `sudo`. Then I tried running the file.

The following is a part of the cmake code  -

```
if (BUILD_DOC)
   find_package(Doxygen)
   configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/Doxyfile.in
   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/Doxyfile @ONLY)
   add_custom_target(${PROJECT_NAME}_doc ALL ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE}
   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/Doxyfile)
endif ()
```

Here, it gave me an error message saying that

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:77 (configure_file):    configure_file
>   Problem configuring file

Just so that you know, line 77 is `configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/Doxyfile.in` .

If I add `AND DOXYGEN_FOUND` to the `if` condition, it doesn't execute anything at all which means that it couldn't find a *doxygen executable*. But as I already told, I already installed *doxygen*.

I am new to cmake. So, could anyone please help me with this

Edit:

The OS I am using is Ubuntu 16.04

After I put `if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)` after the command `find_package(doxygen)` it executed, but I got the same *cmake error* in **line 78** instead of **line 77**

Also, now since I got enough information from the comments, I just realized that my problem is more towards finding where the Doxyfile.in file lies than configuring the file. Could anyonee help me with it?

Comment: You may need to install the [doxygen](https://github.com/doxygen) tool. On Linux, it is likely to be packaged, or you could build it from its [source repository](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am using linux only (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Then you probably need to `apt-get install doxygen`

Comment: Does the file `doc/Doxyfile.in` exist in the source directory?

Comment: By the way, "doxygen executable not found" is a misleading question title. Try something like "CMake Error (configure_file): configure_file Problem configuring file".

Comment: Variable `DOXYGEN_FOUND` is set **after** successfull call `find_package(Doxygen)`. Checking it before that call has a little sence.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I already executed it using sudo itself

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks, I think I found the mistake because of what you told. But, I tried searching for Doxyfile.in and couldn't find it. What should I do now??

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yeah, you are right. But I got back to the same error again after I put the if condition after find_package

Comment: In the sense the same cmake error

Comment: Well, you have two absolutely **unrelated problems**: Finding doxygen and configuring the file. Which one you want to resolve? Update your question post accordingly.

Comment: @Tsyvarev now at the moment, I think my  problem lies in finding the file

Comment: If you can't find the file, you'll have to ask the maintainer of the package about it. It is not something we'd be able to guess, where your file is located.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is clear

> configure_file Problem configuring file

CMake's [`configure_file(<input> <output>)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html) command is used to copy input file to ouput and replacing `@VARIABLES@` in input by the corresponding value.

```
configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/Doxyfile.in ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/Doxyfile @ONLY)
```

You have to find why this process failed:

1. Make sure `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` contains the correct path to your project, and make sure the file `Doxyfile.in` is is the right folder (<project dir>/doc)
2. Make sure content of `Doxyfile.in` does not contains any syntax error, in particular with @VARIABLES@ that needs to be replaced by their CMake value.

Note that this error has nothing to do with Doxygen on your system, and the fact that CMake actually found it or not.